# How to export design with editable text in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, cs6, image-format

I have a requirement where we upload a poster template on our website and the customer should be able to edit the existing text on the poster something like canva.com

please suggest if we can export the design from Photoshop to suit this need.

Comment: I do not think this is possible

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be able to use a generic format that preserves text. That could be PDF format (formally Adobe "portable document format"). The pro versions of Acrobat allow fonts to be embedded and the text to be edited (with some limitations). Also, PDF files can contain vector, raster, text, comments, and printing metadata.

The EPS format (encapsulated postscript, also developed by Adobe) has similar capabilities, and can be opened and edited in Acrobat and Illustrator, among others.

Of course, there are always limitations when going between proprietary software and generic formats. You should test this on various platforms and with various versions of the software. Since this is going to be web-based, you might even need to develop a web application that allows text to be specified separately from a background image, which could probably be done easily with Javascript.

Comment: Yes, a PDF is the correct tool.  With recent versions of InDesign you can export directly to form-fillable PDFs (though final tweaking is still best done in Acrobat).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make a graphic that is editable by the end user (unless the end user has Photoshop) in Photoshop.

Comment: you mean "*unless* the end user has Photoshop." Or a program which can edit PSDs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to understand what you need without the technical background of your application, but basically a jpg as a background image will work on a web-based program.

Answer (score 0):

Actually This is not a PSD file.

Your customers can not edit PSD as professional as an artist. Therefore you need transform PSD/Designs to HTML5 + CSS3.

Here is the [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).